# Does windbg deal with paged out code in kernel by itself when displaying memory content?

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg, wdk

I am using windbg to display some memory using dd address, But the content is shown as question marks.

Could this be because that the memory address is paged out? i know for a fact that the address is correct.

so my question is : Does windbg deal with paged out memory when i use dd or not?

Comment: you should add the os version and windbg version to the query it is a mess out there with 1803 1909 20h2 xxxy yzzb bccd  os with 16349,18362,19041 windbg one working in 20h2 other not working in xxyy  dd willshow question marks if the page is not resident you can use .pagein command if it the memory was paged out

Comment: @blabb i am using windows 7 with windbg 10.0.18

Comment: @blabb so if its paged out, when i use dd should it print ?? ?? ?? or it should bring it back to memory by itself? basically how can i tell if a memory is paged out or just wrong address?

Comment: No .pagein cannot alter  the state of underlying operating system. it is just a command that says one needs a page paged in.  after this command you have to execute the target and the os in target   pages in the page. Read the Documentation it explains all the nuances of all the scenarios  like what if already paged in ,what if bad address what if different process context what if os not minimum applicable etc etc ussrhero linked to the document in his answer below

Answer (score 0):

During a live kernel debugging you can load a page with a command '.pagein'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-pagein--page-in-memory-

Comment: So if its paged out, when i use dd should it print ?? ?? ?? or it should bring it back to memory by itself? basically how can i tell if a memory is paged out or just wrong address?

Comment: Debugger cannot load a page itself. '.pagein' command only marks a page to be loaded. Then you must run a system by 'go' command end OS will load the page and stop once again.